# Creating Click Package (of linux ubuntu) of a Java Swing Application

Tags: java, linux, swing, ubuntu

I've a Java Swing based application along with the dependencies for it in lib folder. How can I create Click Package for this Java Swing Application. As I want to publish it into Linux ubuntu - Software Centre (Developer Tools) category?

Yes, I have a jar which contains the main program and in the lib folder contains some other jars as the dependencies, I run it on windows using start.bat which sets the class path to lib and executives the main jar.

What I want this application to appear in Software Centre (Developers Tools) category in linux ubuntu,
I am trying to follow this http://developer.ubuntu.com/en/publish/ but not sure what needs to be done, kindly help.

Comment: What exactly you mean by "How can I create Click Package for this Java Swing Application"? did you mean jar file and ship it to Ubuntu? sorry but its not clear..

Comment: Consider using [tag:java-web-start] to deploy your application.

Comment: I've have modified the question, please check